# Add annotation programmatically to core plot scatter plot give the X (date value) and Y

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, annotations, core-plot

I am drawing a stock price chart using Core Plot objective-c library.
I need to add annotations to the graph (preferably custom view), programmatically, not on graph touch action. I have a list of x&y (x is a date and y is the price).
Is there an easy way to do this? and how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code block:

```
self.priceAnnotation.anchorPlotPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anchorX, anchorY, nil]; 
// 8 - Add the annotation 
[plot.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:self.priceAnnotation]; // change variable names accordingly
```

For more details, refer this one, answer for your question is already available here; 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2

This tutorial is really helpful. Part-1 and Part-2 both.

Comment: This code is used on selection barPlot:barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:: but i want to render the graph with the annotations without any interaction from the user.

Comment: Yes but use the same code in your own method. Only thing you require is plot object creation manually.